# JsonProperty when source and destination requires different variable names

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I have a source A, a wrapper API B and a destination C.
I have to call wrapper API B from destination C. I have no access to source A.

source A produces following json output:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"created_on" : "27July"
}
```

In wrapper API B, I am consuming the above JSON output using following POJO:

```
class B
{
Long id;
String created_on;
}
```

Wrapper API is able to get the value of created_on from source A. When I call A from B, I get this ouptut:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"created_on" : "27July"
}
```

But in destination C, i have the following POJO:

```
class C
{ 
Long id
String createdOn 
}
```

When I call Wrapper API B from C, i am not able to get the field 'createdOn'.
When I call B from C, i get only this:

```
{
          "id" : 1
}
```

The mapping between created_on and createdOn is not happening.
Basically, i want to return 'createdOn' from Wrapper API B instead of 'created_on'.
Currently, wrapper B is sending 'created_on' , but i want it to return 'createdOn'.
How do I do it? I have tried @JSONProperty but it is not working

Comment: `@JsonProperty` should work. Or `@JsonNaming`. It would be helpful to see a [mcve].

Comment: where do i add the @JsonProperty, should I add it in Destination C's POJO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class C { 
    Long id
    @JsonProperty("created_on")
    String createdOn 
}
```

It's should works.